# Extract all lines between two strings in tabular form within a text file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a text file with multiple repeating tables in it.

It looks something like the following

```
Header1 header2 header3
number1 number2 number3

end_pattern junk junk junk

header1 header2 header3
number3 number4 number5

end_pattern junk junk junk
```

My goal is to put all of the data between between header 1 and not including end_pattern into a list to then bring it into a dataframe.

Ideally I would want to not have the headers repeat multiple times and just have the list with one set of headers and all of the data values under it.

As of now I have pieced together the following code,

```
fh=open(input_file,"r").readlines()

newfile=[]
name_list=['Header1']
for line in name_list:
    A = fh[[s for s,name in enumerate(fh) if line in name][0]:]
    B = A[:[e+1 for e,end in enumerate(A) if 'end_pattern' in end][0]]
    newfile.append(B)
```

However, I am encountering a few issues.

1. It is only copying the first table.
2. It is still including the line with end_pattern junk junk

The output I want is essentially

```
Header1 header2 header3
number1 number2 number3
number4 number5 number6
```

Any thoughts/ possibly a better way to achieve this result is welcome.

Thank you for your time

Comment: If it's only one text file then you could use `grep` or a decent text editor to replace lines matching the regex `^end_pattern.*$` with nothing and save it as a new file.  Then use `pd.read_csv()` on your new file which will skip blank lines by default.

Comment: Does it mean there is only one "torn" table in the file?

Comment: Multiple tables with the same header

Comment: Is the header known or is it the fiirst line? Check [this approach](https://ideone.com/oJERgc).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/oJERgc - is this logic OK?

Comment: Header is not in the first line, there is a lot of junk above the header. But the header name is known

Comment: Also can you post the code not on a third party website?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use partition function:

```py
fh = open(input_file,"r")
output_list=[Header1 header2 header3]

while fh.count(header1)>0: 
   output_list.append(fh.partition(Header1 header2 header3)[2].partition(end_pattern)[0] #takes what's between headers and end_patern without them
   fh=fh.partition(end_pattern)[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools groupby, takewhile, and filterfalse

```
import itertools as it
# ...


def is_header(line):
    return line.lower().startswith('header1 header2 header3')


def not_footer(line):
    return not line.startswith('end_pattern')


def doit():
    newfile = []

    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        for in_header, group in it.groupby(f, key=is_header):
            if in_header:
                if not newfile:
                    newfile.append(next(group))
            elif newfile:
                possible_rows = it.takewhile(not_footer, group)
                newfile.extend(it.filterfalse(str.isspace, possible_rows))  # no empty lines

    # print out the file contents
    for x in newfile:
        print(x, end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    doit()
```